# Transferring a folder from box to google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a folder on box [which I do not own, it was shared with me] that I want to move directly into google colab (Its too big to store on computer). The ways I've found involve using wget to download a single file, which does not work for folders.
Does anyone know a way to do this, either by using wget or something similar to download directly into colab, or to move from box to google drive and then mount drive to colab?
Here is the format of the link I was given: `https://subdomain.app.box.com/s/asefsc5xtj76mw13epuwgg6dobv`
Thank you in advance.

I tried using wget to download it directly into a zip file, however that did not work out.